# Error in cross validation with factor value

Tags: r, machine-learning, cross-validation

I have this code:

```
# Define training control
set.seed(123) 
train.control <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10)
# Train the model
model <- train(is_nocnv ~., data = mydata, method = "lm", trControl = train.control)


# Summarize the results
print(model)
```

When I execute this code I obtain this error:

```
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
 contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

The field: is_nocnv is factor the value of this field is 'YES' , 'NO'

```
str(mydata)
'data.frame':   8334 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ chr         : Factor w/ 1 level "chr1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ start       : int  3218610 154080441 154089408 61735 2069681 2074104   3135175 3137913 3214732 5901288 ...
 $ stop        : int  154074261 154081058 247813706 2061969 2071738 3130590 3136858 3212946 5900106 5902086 ...
 $ strand      : Factor w/ 1 level "*": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ num_probes  : int  69643 3 59364 379 2 333 2 33 1943 3 ...
 $ segment_mean: num  -0.122 -13.462 -0.1 -0.326 -25.242 ...
 $ is_nocnv    : Factor w/ 2 levels "NO","YES": 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Here a small part of my dataset (csv)

```
"chr","start","stop","strand","num_probes","segment_mean","is_nocnv"
chr1,3218610,154074261,*,69643,-0.122,YES
chr1,154080441,154081058,*,3,-13.462,YES
chr1,154089408,247813706,*,59364,-0.1003,YES
chr1,61735,2061969,*,379,-0.326,NO
chr1,2069681,2071738,*,2,-25.242,NO
chr1,2074104,3130590,*,333,-0.3957,NO
```

Comment: Looks like you have only one factor level in `is_nocnv` in `mydata`. Try `unique(mydata$is_nocnv)`

Comment: is_nocnv have two value: 'YES','NO'

Comment: Can you use `table(mydata$is_nocnv)` and show us the actual counts of Yes/No? I think the problem is that during the cross-validation the subset of data the model uses has only one level.

Comment: @AntoniosK the command table(mydata$is_nocnv) produce this :   NO  YES 
6992 1342

Comment: What I mentioned above could be possible. Can you use a smaller number of cross-validations to see if it works ok? Maybe `trainControl(method = "cv", number = 2)` ?

Comment: @AntoniosK with number = 2 I obtain same error

Comment: Can you show the output of `str(mydata)`? It may be that one of the explanatory variables is the problem

Comment: @see24 I update my question with your request.

Comment: I think you should remove variables `chr` and `strand` as they have only 1 level.

Comment: @AntoniosK if i insert this : model <- train(is_nocnv ~start + stop + num_probes + segment_mean, data = mydata, method = "lm", trControl = train.control) I obtain this error: Error: wrong model type for classification

Comment: Is `mydata` a dataframe or a tibble? If it's a tibble try to make it a dataframe and try again.

Comment: @AntoniosK thanks for the answer, mydata is a dataframe in my post there is str(mydata)

Comment: No idea why it doesn't work. Can you post a sample of your data using `dput()` so I can replicate your problem?

Comment: It looks like the problem after removing variables with only 1 level is that your response variable `is_noncv` is a factor and the method you supplied is lm. You can't perform linear regression with a factor as response.

Comment: Yes @see24 that makes sense! Completely missed that. It should work if `method="glm", family="binomial"` is used in this case.

Comment: @see24 I insert this line : model <- train(is_nocnv ~., data = mydata, method="glm",family="binomial", trControl = train.control)  but I obtain same error: Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels

Comment: I insert small part of my dataset in the post. Thanks

Comment: Your new code still includes variables with one level. You need to do both (a) glm model (b) remove any input variables with one level. Try this: `train(is_nocnv ~ start + stop + num_probes + segment_mean, data = mydata, method="glm",family="binomial", trControl = train.control)`

Comment: @AntoniosK WORK. Thank you very much!!

Comment: That's great! However, I have to say that `start` and `stop` columns seem to be `datetime` variables that are stored as `integer` values for some reason. You should think if you want to recode them somehow, instead of using those integer values. Does it make sense?

Comment: @AntoniosK thank you for your suggestion :)